# How to set the ssl globally for all the feature files

Tags: karate

As Part of our automation we need to set the ssl certificate.

If I am setting in the feature file (as shown below) it works perfectly fine. But I have huge number of feature files and want to define this globally so that this ssl is used in all the feature files.

And configure ssl = { keyStore: 'wmcloudPreProd2_truststore.jks', keyStorePassword: 'manage', keyStoreType: 'jks' };

Looking for a way to define this ssl configuration for complete automation project.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, in `karate-config.js` you can do:

```
karate.configure('ssl', { keyStore: 'wmcloudPreProd2_truststore.jks', keyStorePassword: 'manage', keyStoreType: 'jks' });
```

This is mentioned in the doc: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure

Comment: Great ...Working perfectly fine. Thank you Peter for quick and accurate response